# C# Remove object from list of objects

Tags: c#

I have a list of objects and I am trying to remove a specific object in the list by first checking a property in the object.

Originally I used a `foreach` but then realised you can't use this while modifying a collection, so I decided to use a normal `for` but then I'm not sure how to write code that does what I originally wrote.

How do I go about writing code to do what I originally had?

Thanks

Here's my code:

```
    public void DeleteChunk(int ChunkID)
    {
        //foreach (Chunk i in ChunkList)
        //{
        //    if (i.UniqueID == ChunkID)
        //    {
        //        ChunkList.Remove(i);
        //    }
        //}

        //This won't work because here i is just an integer so i.UniqueID won't exist.
        for (int i = 0; i < ChunkList.Capacity; i++)
        {
            if (i.UniqueID == ChunkID)
            {
                ChunkList.Remove(i);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: "This won't work" is *not* a good description of what goes wrong.

Comment: What type is `ChunkList`?

Comment: Remember `Capacity` and `Count` are different and may not be the same.

Answer (score 107):

You can simplify this with linq:

```
var item = ChunkList.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UniqueId == ChunkID);
if (item != null)
    ChunkList.Remove(item);
```

You can also do the following, which will also work if there is more than one match:

```
ChunkList.RemoveAll(x => x.UniqueId == ChunkID);
```

Comment: But for list there is no Remove(Predicate), it needs to be RemoveAll()

Comment: x.UniqueID does not have an extension method, apparently.

Comment: Do you mean `ChunkList`?  What type is `ChunkList`?

Comment: private List<Chunk> ChunkList = new List<Chunk>();
Chunk being a class with some properties in it.

Comment: The above should work then.  Are you sure you have the syntax correct?

Answer (score 19):

You're removing and then incrementing, which means you'll be one ahead of yourself.  Instead, remove in reverse so you never mess up your next item.

```
for (int i = ChunkList.Count-1; i >=0; i--)
{
    if (ChunkList[i].UniqueID == ChunkID)
    {
        ChunkList.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work, because I get "The best overload method for... has some invalid arguments" when I hover over ChunkList.Remove(i)

Comment: @0x4C4A41 You need to provide the type of collection that ChunkList is in order to ensure we provide correct help.  Otherwise, we can only guide you so far.

Comment: Try `ChunkList.RemoveAt(i)`

Comment: private List<Chunk> ChunkList = new List<Chunk>();
Chunk being a class with some properties in it. ChunkList.RemoveAt seems to work thanks

Answer (score 11):

If `ChunkList` is `List<Chunk>`, you can use the `RemoveAll` method:

```
ChunkList.RemoveAll(chunk => chunk.UniqueID == ChunkID);
```

Answer (score 8):

First you have to find out the object in the list. Then you can remove from the list.

```
       var item = myList.Find(x=>x.ItemName == obj.ItemName);
       myList.Remove(item);
```

Comment: First you have to find out the object in the list. Then you can remove from the list.

Comment: do we need to implement IEquatable for this to work? or does it just compare reference?

Answer (score 3):

> Originally I used a foreach but then realised you can't use this while modifying a collection

You can create a copy of the collection and iterate over that using `ToList()` to create to copy:

```
 foreach(Chunk chunk in ChunkList.ToList())
 {
     if (chunk.UniqueID == ChunkID)
     {
         ChunkList.Remove(chunk);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with this code:

- [`Capacity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2.aspx) represents the number of items the list can contain before resizing is required, not the actual count; you need to use [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3.aspx) instead, and
- When you remove from the list, you should go backwards, otherwise you could skip the second item when two identical items are next to each other.

Answer (score 2):

You're checking `i`'s `UniqueID` while `i` is actually an integer. You should do something like that, if you want to stay with a `for` loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ChunkList.Capacity; i++)
{
    if (ChunkList[i].UniqueID == ChunkID)
    {
        ChunkList.Remove(i);
    }
}
```

You can, and should, however, use linq:

```
ChunkList.Remove(x => x.UniqueID == ChunkID);
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you are using `Capacity` instead of `Count`.

Secondly, if you *only* need to delete *one* item, then you can happily use a loop. You just need to ensure that you break out of the loop after deleting an item, like so:

```
int target = 4;

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; ++i)
{
    if (list[i].UniqueID == target)
    {
        list.RemoveAt(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

If you want to remove *all* items from the list that match an ID, it becomes even easier because you can use [`List<T>.RemoveAll(Predicate<T> match)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx)

```
int target = 4;

list.RemoveAll(element => element.UniqueID == target);
```

Answer (score 1):

One technique is to create a copy of the collection you want to modify, change the copy as needed, then replace the original collection with the copy at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a while loop to delete item/items matching ChunkID. Here is my suggestion:

```
public void DeleteChunk(int ChunkID)
{
   int i = 0;
   while (i < ChunkList.Count) 
   {
      Chunk currentChunk = ChunkList[i];
      if (currentChunk.UniqueID == ChunkID) {
         ChunkList.RemoveAt(i);
      }
      else {
        i++;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution without using LINQ:

```
    Chunk toRemove = null;
    foreach (Chunk i in ChunkList)
    {
        if (i.UniqueID == ChunkID)
        {
            toRemove = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (toRemove != null) {
        ChunkList.Remove(toRemove);
    }
```

(If Chunk is a struct, then you can use Nullable<Chunk> to achieve this.)